# How to parse invalid JSON with unquoted keys using ActiveSupport 3 (Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I need to parse certain invalid JSON in Ruby.

Something like:

```
json_str = '{name:"Javier"}'
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode json_str
```

As you can see, it's invalid because the hash key is not quoted, it should be

```
json_str = '{"name":"Javier"}'
```

But that can't be changed and I have to parse the keys unquoted.

I could parse it with ActiveSupport 2.x, but ActiveSupport 3 doesn't allow me.  It throws me:

```
Yajl::ParseError: lexical error: invalid string in json text.
                                      {name:"Javier"}
                     (right here) ------^
```

By the way, it's a Ruby application using some Rails libraries, but it's not a Rails application

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is this invalid json coming from?  A rest api or some file?  It would be best to actually fix the json, a parser that accepts invalid json is bad and I am glad they are using Yajl now.

Comment: Yes it's an API.  And yeah it stinks that I have to make a workaround for this but I don't have any contact with the developers of the API.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to fix this invalid JSON:

```
json_str = '{name:"Javier"}'
json_str.gsub!(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/, '"\2":')
hash = Yajl::Parser.parse(json_str)
```

Comment: Better hope there are no colons in any of your values

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat robust regex you can use. It's not perfect -- specifically it doesn't work in some corner cases where the values themselves contain json-like text, but it will work in most general cases:

```
quoted_json = unquoted_json.gsub(/([{,]\s*)(\w+)(\s*:\s*["\d])/, '\1"\2"\3')
```

First it looks for either a `{` or `,` which are the options for the character preceding a key name (also allows any amount of whitespace with `\s*`). It captures this as a group:

```
([{,]\s*)
```

Then it captures the key itself, which is composed of letters, digits, and underscores (which regex conveniently supplies a `\w` character class for):

```
(\w+)
```

Finally, it matches what must follow a key name; i.e. a colon followed by either a start quote (for a string value) or a digit (for a numeric value). Also allows extra whitespace, and captures the whole thing in a group:

```
(\s*:\s*["\d])
```

For each match, it just puts the three pieces back together, but with quotes around the key (so quotes around capture group #2):

```
'\1"\2"\3'
```

Comment: That's really good but it also won't catch nested values. This goes a bit further to include those and uses a zero width assertion at the end so things such as the 4 in `{-234: {4: [{'bleh'...` can still be fixed:
`quoted_json.gsub(/([{,]\s*)'?([\-\w\d]+)'?(\s*:\s*(?=[\[{"'\d]))/, '\1"\2"\3')`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
require 'json'
json_str = '{name:"Javier"}'
hash = JSON::parse( json_str.gsub( /{|:"/, {'{'=>'{"', ':"'=>'":"'} ) )
```

Comment: Wow I thought that I could fix that without pre-parsing the JSON (maybe activating some kind of ActiveSupport flag).  I'm going to take a closer look at that code and let you know how it works for me.

Comment: sorry, it raised me a SyntaxError exception: `invalid regular expression; there's no previous pattern, to which '{' would define cardinality at 1: /{|:"/`